# UDP socket not responding

Tags: sockets, udp

I'm writing a sample of c udp socket.
This is the client

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s ip port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int sock;
    char *server_ip;
    unsigned short server_port;
    struct sockaddr_in cliAddr, serAddr;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_ip = argv[1];
    server_port = atoi(argv[2]);

    memset(&cliAddr, 0, sizeof(cliAddr));
    cliAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cliAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    cliAddr.sin_port = htons(21152);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&serAddr, 0, sizeof(serAddr));
    serAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
    serAddr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    if (sendto(sock, "hello", 5, 0, (struct sockaddr *) (&serAddr), sizeof(serAddr)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sendto failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("send success\n");

    int n;
    char recvstr[50];
    if ((n = recvfrom(sock, &recvstr, 50, 0, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "recvfrom failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("receive success: %s\n", recvstr);
    printf("from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(serAddr.sin_port));

    exit(0);
  }
```

And this is the server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int sock, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char recvstr[50];
    socklen_t cliaddrlen;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    cliaddrlen = sizeof(cliaddr);
    if ((n = recvfrom(sock, recvstr, 50, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "recvfrom failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("client ip: %s, client port: %d\n", inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr), ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

    if (sendto(sock, "hello from server", 17, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, cliaddrlen) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sendto failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("send success\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

It works fine when client and server are in the local.
Such as "./server 21151" and "./client 127.0.0.1 21151".
The server will get:

```
client ip: 127.0.0.1, client port: 21152
send success
```

And the client will get:

```
send success
receive success: hello from serverB
from 127.0.0.1:21151
```

But when i change the ip to public ip.The client cannot get the response
from server.
The client will stop at the function recvfrom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess - you are running this on a Mac and the firewall is on? The default filtering rules will allow sending UDP out and receiving a response (the client), but will not allow to receive unsolicited datagrams on an open socket (the server).

Your code is fine otherwise, though you don't necessarily need to `bind(2)` the client side of the socket. The kernel will assign next available high-numbered port for the source. You might instead consider using `connect(2)` on the client if you plan on any extended conversation between given client and server.

You also *always* want to explicitly zero-terminate strings received from the network. Not doing this has been the source of endless remote exploits.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes,i'm running this on a Mac.
I want to write a udp hole punching sample.So i bind the client side of the socket.
How to achieve?

Comment: Using function connect can achieve?

Comment: By `connect()`-ing UDP socket you don't have to use destination address on every `send()`, and set a filter on `recv()`, so you only get datagrams from the "connected" peer.

Comment: I save the client ip and port.Can i connect to the client in a new process?

Comment: Connect - no. You can just `sendto()` that IP/port.

Comment: Does NAT have a expire date?Can the client receive the message when the server sendto() that IP/port?

Comment: That depends on the NAT device.